# How to check if Literal exists in server side?

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 aspx pages that uses the same aspx.cs file using CodeFile

I have on one aspx page but not on the other aspx page.

On runtime I want to check if the Literal exist then set the value if it doesn't do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using FindControl method?

```
Literal l = FindControl("control id");

if(l != null)
{
    //do your processing
}
```